# Parsing context-free languages in a stream of tokens

Tags: algorithm, parsing, context-free-grammar

### The problem

Given a context-free grammar with arbitrary rules and a stream of tokens, how can stream fragments that match the grammar be identified effectively?

### Example:

#### Grammar

```
S -> ASB | AB
A -> a 
B -> b
```

(So essentially, a number of `a`s followed by an equal number of `b`s)

#### Stream:

```
aabaaabbc...
```

#### Expected result:

1. Match starting at position 1: ab
2. Match starting at position 4: aabb

Of course the key is "effectively". without testing too many hopeless candidates for too long. The only  thing I know about my data is that although the grammar is arbitrary, in practice matching sequences will be relatively short (<20 terminals) while the stream itself will be quite long (>10000 terminals).

Ideally I'd also want a syntax tree but that's not too important, because once the fragment is identified, I can run an ordinary parser over it to obtain the tree.

Where should I start? Which type of parser can be adapted to this type of work?

Comment: For an arbitrary grammar I see no choice but to start a new match attempt at each symbol.  If you can code your parser with specific knowledge, only then you can cheat (i.e. if the first symbol must be X, no need to start new match attempts except at an X).

Comment: Recommend you change your first grammar rule to "S -> AB | ASB" or something equivalent. Right now it appears as if your grammar only matches infinite strings of balanced ab.

Comment: @ccoakley Thanks, and well spotted. I tried so hard to come up with a really simple example that I ended up getting it wrong. :)

Comment: Hard to tell. You've not quite said What type of work this is. Can the grammar be recognized by an LALR parser? LL(k)? LR(k)? GLR? other?

Comment: @harold I was kinda hoping that to be part of the answer. The grammar can be anything as things stand now, but if there is a very good solution for a class of CFGs, that's a compelling argument for limiting or transforming the grammar.

Comment: The problem is that most parsing algorithms for context-free gramars require knowledge of the end of a string - whether a special symbol like `$` or the empty string `λ`. If you're going to parse an incoming token sequence for matches, I don't see any option but to parse each individual substring. In this case, parsing using the CYK algorithm is probably the best option, because it has the best worst-case complexity of the parsing algorithms for context-free languages. I'm sure there's research into on-the-fly context-free parsing, however, that you could look up.

Answer (score 1):

"Arbitrary grammar" makes me suggest you look at wberry's comment.

How complex are these grammars? Is there a manual intervention step?

I'll make an attempt. If I modified your example grammar from:

```
S -> ASB | AB
A -> a 
B -> b
```

to include:

```
S' -> S | GS' | S'GS' | S'G
G -> sigma*
```

So that G = garbage and S' is many S fragments with garbage in between (I may have been careless with my production rules. You get the idea), I think we can solve your problem. You just need a parser that will match other rules before G. You may have to modify these production rules based on the parser. I almost guarantee that there will be rule ordering changes depending on the parser. Since most parser libraries separate lexing from parsing, you'll probably need a catch-all lexeme followed by modifying G to include all possible lexemes. Depending on your specifics, this might not be any better (efficiency-wise) than just starting each attempt at each spot in the stream.

But... Assuming my production rules are fixed (both for correctness and for the particular flavor of parser), this should not only match fragments in the stream, but it should give you a parse tree for the whole stream. You are only interested in subtrees rooted in nodes of type S.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution will work as intended. In the example grammar, a string like `ababababab` should match the derivation `S => AB -> ab` five times. But adding "garbage rules" will give you derivations like `S' => GS' => ababababS' => ababababAB => ababababab`. So the garbage derivation means you're going to need to enumerate all possible derivations, then choose the derivation with the greatest number of non-garbage derivations, or order the derivations rules so non-garbage derivations come last. Is this a more optimal solution than just matching subsequences using CYK or something?

Comment: @danportin : depending on the parser-generator tool, there should be ways to do reluctant matching. Unfortunately, I know of no universally applicable way. That's why I loaded my answer with caveats, and specifically mentioned having to reorder the rules to achieve the desired results. I'm still assuming it's easier to get a parser tool to work than to write one from scratch. I implemented Earley to do some static analysis on C, only to realize that my grammer was ambiguous (it worked in yacc) and I had a miserable time modifying the code to generate the "correct" parse tree from the table.